# Timer is not working for file creation using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, timer

I am doing backup schedule every day. If any backup file is not created within 24 hours, I want to create new backup file (executing `backupdatabase()` function).

In addition, I have used a timer, so that every hour it will be checked whether the file  is created or not. And after 24 hours it will create a  new file (executing `backupdatabase()` function).

File checking is done by using `File.GetcreationTime`. Whether the file is created or not.

For that I have done like this...

```
public partial class BackupForm : Form
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private Int32 _hours = 0;
    private const Int32 RUN_AT = 10;

    private void BackupForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        _hours = (24 - (DateTime.Now.Hour + 1)) + RUN_AT;
        _timer = new Timer { Interval = _hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 };
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Tick);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        var name = "localhost";
        const string path = @"C:\Creation\Name\backupdb\";
        var listfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Creation\Name\backupdb\", "backup-*.zip").ToList();
        var files = listfiles.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var creationtime = File.GetCreationTime(file);
            var diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(creationtime);
            if (diff.Hours > 24 && diff.Days < 2 && creationtime.Month == dt.Month && creationtime.Year == dt.Year && name == "localhost" && _hours == 24)
            {
                backupDatabase();
            }
            else if (_hours != 24)
            {
                _hours = 24;
                _timer.Interval = _hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            }
        }
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it does not check the file creation time and even it does not create the file after 24 hours.

How to check the file with creation time along with timer for every one hour and after 24 hours how to create the file?

Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: is this question is unclear then pls leave a comment here...

Comment: yes it does not goes into this function "void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)"

Comment: Would any one pls help on this...

Comment: What does this mean? Actually which time interval are you trying to calculate? `hours = (24 - (DateTime.Now.Hour + 1)) + RUN_AT;   _timer = new Timer { Interval = _hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 }; `

Comment: @sll I am assuming , i am assigning 24 hours time interval to the timer ..but not sure this is correct method.. or not pls help on this..

Comment: @sll my aim is i have to check the file creation time coming from directory every hour up to 24 hours so ....after 24 hours i have to create new file (excution of method backupdatabase())...

Comment: @sll would you pls help on this....

Comment: Could you put a break point and see what exactly was calculated by `Interval = _hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 `?

Comment: @sll it was showing interval is 79200000.0 like this..

Comment: 22 hours, I would suggest in debugger substitute this large value by some more feasible like 60000 (1minute) and then see whether Tick emthod executes and does what you are expecting. In this case very helpful unit tests which perfectly show problems on the earlier stages

Comment: @sll  the tick does not executing and i have tried this .... var        minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
      var adjust = 10 - (minute%10);      
      _timer = new Timer();
      _timer.Interval = adjust * 60;   for checking every one hour whether the tick method is executing or not ...but it does not executing ..... would you pls suggest any ideas and about unit test also ..

Comment: @sll is this possible can we enter into chat discussion.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4799/discussion-between-rockyashkumar-and-sll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a method that runs every hour you need to assign a one hour interval to the timer.  Timer.Interval is expecting a value in milliseconds so:

```
// 1000 ms per second, 60 seconds per minute, and 60 minutes per hour
_timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60;
```

This will make the timer "tick" every hour.  Inside the Timer_Tick function you should simply check for file dates that are within the last hour:

```
var creationtime = File.GetCreationTime(file);
var diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(creationtime);

if (diff.TotalHours <= 1)
{
    // File was created within the last hour
}
```

However, I believe what you are really trying to achieve a solution where you simply create a backup if one has not been created within 24 hours.  To achieve this you would use the following:

1)  Create a new method called BackupIfNecessary()

```
private void BackupIfNecessary()
{
    var name = "localhost";
    const string path = @"C:\Creation\Name\backupdb\";
    var listfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Creation\Name\backupdb\", "backup-*.zip").ToList();
    var files = listfiles.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();

    DateTime lastBackup = DateTime.MinValue;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var creationtime = File.GetCreationTime(file);

        // Check if the creation date for this file is the "latest"
        if (creationtime > lastBackup)
        {
            // Store as the "latest" time
            lastBackup = creationtime;
        }
    }

    var diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastBackup);
    if (diff.TotalHours >= 24)
    {
        // The last backup file was created over 24 hours ago; You should create the file
    }
}
```

2)  When your form loads, execute the backup function for the first time by calling BackupIfNecessary in Form_Load (so you don't wait full 24 hours for the first run)

3)  Set a timer interval for 24 hours in Form_Load:

```
// 1000 ms per second, 60 seconds per minute, and 60 minutes per hour, and 24 hours per day
_timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

4)  Inside of Timer_Tick simply call BackupIfNecessary() which will check if a backup has been created within the last 24 hours, if not it will create one

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary problem is this line:

```
var files = listfiles.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
```

That's going to give you file names that have no path information. That is, "backup-x.zip". You're then passing that name to `File.GetCreationTime`. If your program's current working directory isn't the directory that contains those files, `File.GetCreationTime` is going to throw an exception because it can't find the file.

You probably need the full path name from `listfiles`.

You never see the exception because . . .

You're using `System.Timers.Timer`, which hides bugs by swallowing exceptions. If your `Tick` event handler throws an exception, it will escape to the code that called the event handler (the `Timer` code), and will be swallowed. You will never see the exception.

In your event handler, you have:
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        // do a bunch of stuff
        _timer.End();
    }

If something in there throws an exception, then the event handler will exit without restarting the timer. I would suggest that you change that:

```
{
    _timer.Stop();
    try
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
    catch (whatever exceptions)
    {
        // notify of exception
    }
    finally
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```